# How to replace &nbsp; without MariaDB Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I see SQL examples of replacing `&nbsp;` in MySQL/MariaDB databases:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&nbsp;', ' ');
```

... but this statement throws an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near ''&nbsp)' at line 1
```

I see the `''` and `)'` - I've tried escaping the semicolon with a backslash `\`:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&nbsp\;', ' ');
```

... but get about the same error. Actually, I see many SQL examples for MySQL/MariaDB and they aren't escaping either the semicolon or the ampersand.

***EDIT***

@Barmar recommended running the SQL from the command line. I logged into MariaDB and entered use 'use mydatabase'. The prompt changed to indicate the current db and I entered the command as above. The command was accepted without error, over 2300 matches were found, but nothing was changed:

```
MariaDB [mydatabase]> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â&nbsp;', ' ');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)
Rows matched: 2330  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Why was there nothing changed?

***EDIT - Include WHERE***

I'm getting more and more confused. From within **phpMyAdmin**:

`SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â %';`  <<== Returns 1715 rows

Yet also in phpMyAdmin:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'Â ', ' ') WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â %';`   <<== Returns 0 matched rows

From the CLI:

`SELECT COUNT(*) from wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE 'Â ';`   <<== Returns 0

`SELECT COUNT(*) from wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE 'Â';`   <<== Returns 8

I'm totally lost on what to think of these differences. For sure I know that funky `Â` exists all over my wp_posts. I can see it in the data using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `'&nbsp)` somewhere in your code (without a closing quote)?

Comment: @jpaugh Absolutely certain. This is a single line of SQL. I've stared at it for too long ... The SQL is copy/paste in the first `UPDATE ...` shown in my question. You must be telling me it should work as-is?

Comment: I think it should. But, I've been away from mysql for too long to be sure.

Comment: Are you running it from a programming language or script? Show the code that executes the query.

Comment: I see examples both ways (escaped/and not).

Comment: @Barmar That is the entire code - I am using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: The error message says that the query contains `&nbsp` followed immediately by `)`. It can't be coming from the query you posted, since there are several characters before the `)`.

Comment: Have you tried the following (to ensure the `&nbsp;` is really the source of the problem)? `REPLACE(post_content, ' ', ' ');`

Comment: @Barmar I'm with you.... I've deleted the entire line and retyped it to be sure.

Comment: Sounds like a PhpMyAdmin bug, probably because it runs in the browser and `&nbsp;` has special meaning to browsers. It might be trying to prevent XSS and messing up the query.

Comment: Can you use the CLI `mysql` client instead of PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @jpaugh I just tried that. No error after replacing `&nbsp;` with `' '` - but the weird thing is that Simulate shows no matches for a single space.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not real good with the CLI but I can handle researching the command line to do it.

Comment: Just type `mysql`, you'll get a `mysql>` prompt. Enter your query there. Type `quit` to get out.[

Comment: @Barmar I entered the query through the CLI but no changes were made even though there were 2300+ matches (see my edit).

Comment: There were 2300 matches because you have no `WHERE` clause, so all rows match the condition (since there's no condition). But none of them have `Â&nbsp;`

Comment: You have an extra `Â` character before `&`.

Comment: @Barmar That char is intentional, although I completely excluded it while trying the &nbsp; replace above. I thought that character might be causing the issue so I removed it temporarily during troubleshooting.

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) from wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%Â&nbsp;%'` return?

Comment: @Barmar It returns COUNT(*) with `0` underneath it. Last line says `1 row in set (0.26 sec)`

Comment: @Barmar It looks like the data is stored as 'Â ' in the database but is displaying as 'Â&nbsp;' on the frontend when displayed. I'd replace only the 'Â', but there are other occurrences of it with variations - so I have to include the space in this instance.

Comment: Maybe your application that displays the data translates spaces to `&nbsp;` to ensure that they get displayed literally.

Answer (score 1):

`'Â&nbsp;'` leads me to believe that the problem is not what you think it is.

Do debug, do `SELECT HEX(col)...` for one of the source lines that you are trying to fix.  I suspect you will find `C2A0` in the hex string.  That is the utf8 encoding for what gets turned into `&nbsp;` when using htmlentities().

You may also have an issue with character sets.  Please find out what settings are in effect in phpmyadmin; `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`; and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I ask for these because there could be some mix up between latin1 `A0` and a UTF-8 `C2A0` that is adding to the confusion.

In many contexts, a "hard space" (hex `A0`) *looks* like an ordinary space (hex `20`), making it further difficult to decide what is what.

Summarize:

1. Find out what you *really* have via `SELECT HEX()`
2. Fix the settings -- Either use latin1 throughout or use utf8/utf8mb4 throughout.
3. *Then* rethink how to do the replacement (if step 2 did not fix it).

I mostly see `A0` coming from Microsoft Word documents, but there are probably other sources.

When misinterpreted as latin1, the utf8 `C2A0` shows as `Â` (A-circumflex and a space).